# understanding df -h output for use with dd

Tags: partitioning, dd, devices, clone, df

What do the different sda devices represent in this df -h output?

Aren't /var /usr /opt all apart of / (the root directory)? Does this mean those directories are partitioned differently?

```
-bash-3.2$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             7.8G  444M  7.0G   6% /
/dev/sda7              18G  530M   16G   4% /scratch
/dev/sda6             3.9G  293M  3.4G   8% /var
/dev/sda2              12G  2.7G  8.4G  25% /usr
/dev/sda5              20G  633M   18G   4% /opt
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

and if I wanted to clone this system with `dd`, would I have to `dd` each sda device?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. Long ago, /var, /usr. etc might be on different disks...back when disk size was teeny. However, that fell out of fashion decades ago when disks grew large enough to house the entire system. Before mucking with it. ask whoever built they system why they did it. Maybe they had a reason.

Comment: @user535733 There where one more reason for mounting /usr /var and others on separate disks than disk size .. Performance !! A disk can only handle a few IOPS (in these days maybe 60 to 80 IO pr Second. Mounting sub-directories of / on separate disks gave more IOPS.

Comment: @SorenA total agreement. Since neither space nor performance suggest the OP's partitioning, I tried to keep the digression to a minimum. Didn't mean to mislead.

Comment: Why do you have bash 3.2?